# Eclipse has problems with std C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have eclipse with CDT. I now find the funny thing that eclipse ssems not to find the include files for the `std` library.

In the options of the project I added the include path `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.1\include\c++`. Eclipse finds the header files (no error at the `#include` statement, but if I use e.g. `cout` in my code I get an error from the IDE. The compiler behind (g++) has no problems, so it is a configuration problem of eclipse or a bug of eclipse.

If I did not include the path in the properties panel, even the `#include` statement was marked as faulty. The same I have seen for example using a `fostream`, so it seems to be a problem with the whole std library.

So can you tell me where I can look to get these errors away? It's nasty to have a dozen errors all over your files and all of them are only errors in the IDE.

Comment: Please show code... And get off Eclipse CDT. Might I recommend Code:Blocks. I recently switch. Code:Blocks is not perfect but it is head and shoulders better.

Comment: @Lou: Does Code:Blocks support auto-complementation and the other few nice features from eclipse?

Comment: Yes it does. There are some annoyances with the editors auto indenting but I'm sure if I customized the the auto-completion templates, it would be nicer. The thing about Eclipse CDT is that it seems to be an orphan.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your not dealing with a namespace issue, I found my windows projects in code blocks have `-static-libgcc` as part of the link line.